# Extract invoice number, incoice date etc. from scanned invoice as pdf (Java)

Tags: java, pdf, ocr

I, wan't to extract invoice number, invoice date, tax amount and price of a invoice , with Java. The invoice is scanned and saved as PDF. Does anyone know a relatively simple possibility for this?

Comment: yes it's possible :p

Comment: Well ... maybe.  It depends on the PDF.  However, it is really a lot better (and simpler) to get the program that generated the invoice to emit the details in another format as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly possible. Depending on how much effort you're willing to spend, and what context you're going for, you can do at least 2 things:

- use iText7 Core to extract text from your pdf file, then use regular expressions to find something within that text
- use pfd2Data (an add-on for iText7) to match invoices (or other pdf documents) to template documents. If a match succeeds, the pdf2Data produces an xml file that contains all the data from the pdf (that you specified in the template). Extracting data from an xml datasource should be trivial.

http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/content-parsing-extraction-and-redaction-text/itext7-how-read-text-specific-position

http://itextpdf.com/blog/pdf2data-extract-information-invoices-and-templates